# How to use the linear constraints to represent that two intervals are disjoint in linear program

Tags: linear-programming

I want to write a linear program to solve my problem. It is required that two intervals are disjoint in the constraints. For example, there are two intervals, [a, c] and [b, d]. I think that we can use the following constraint to represent that they are disjoint (Specifically, the length of the intersection set is 0):

```
max{a, b} >= min{c, d}
```

In addition, it is also okay in my problem if the constraint is

```
max{a, b} = min{c, d}
```

But both of them are not linear. How can I write an equivalent linear constraint? I do not want to use an integer/binary variable.

Comment: I got a bad feeling about the possibility of expressing this in a convex setting (without the following restriction). Is it really needed, that those intervals can change their roles (no a-priori order? e.g. [a,c] can come *before and after* [b,d])? If not, it seems trivial to just post `c <= b` (and you a-priori defined the order of intervals in your problem).

Comment: The orders of [a, c] and [b, d] are unknown. Therefore, it means that there are several cases, e.g., `c <= b` or `d <= a` or `a = c` or `b = d`.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2480793/linear-programming-preventing-staff-scheduling-shift-overlap) help? This is the standard way to model such constraints.